# Subequations in combination with showonlyrefs does not work

Tags: mathtools

`subequations` in combination with `showonlyrefs` does not work. Is there a workaround.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\begin{document}
\noindent First equation:
\begin{equation}\label{G1}
  c=a+b
\end{equation}
Second equation:
\begin{equation}\label{G2}
  d=a-b
\end{equation}
A group of equations:
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:sub}
  %\noeqref{eq:1,eq:2}
  \begin{gather}
    \frac{\text{d}b_1}{\text{d}z} - \beta_1b_1 = C_{12}b_2,\label{eq:1}\\
    \frac{\text{d}b_2}{\text{d}z} - \beta_2b_2 = C_{21}b_1.\label{eq:2}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
Last equation:
\begin{equation}\label{G4}
  e=a+b+c
\end{equation}
the following equations will be referenced in the doucment:\\
the first equation: \eqref{G1}\\
%the first equation: \eqref{G2}\\
%the group of equations: \eqref{eq:sub} \\
%specific equations out of the group: \eqref{eq:1} und \eqref{eq:2} \\
the last equation \eqref{G4} \qquad ERROR: the label sould be (2) !!!\\
\\
Unfortunately I cannot figure out what's wrong. In the actual configuration I wanted to have the last equation the label (2) sice only the first and last equations are referenced!
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please note, this is an international forum. So can you please ask questions in English? Is you are searching for a German forum, there are, e.g., [TeXwelt](https://www.texwelt.de) or [goLaTeX](https://www.golatex.de).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The vast majority of participants on this site do not read, let alone understand, German. Please edit your posting so that it uses English.

Comment: Unrelated, your use of `\text{d}` is wrong, use something like `\mathrm{d}` (`\text{d}` is (1) the text font, and (2) will follow the font outside of math, and thus be italic if the text is italic, which of course if not what you want)

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/latex3/mathtools/issues

Comment: The main problem here is that subequations saves the current value of the `equation` counter and restores it again afterwards. You get the same problem if for some reason you, say, combine `subequations` and `gather*` and disable `showonlyrefs'`, the result is the same. Not sure what would be a good solution here.

Comment: Welcome among us. Please use English as it is what everyone here reads/writes. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `subequations` env is simply not geared towards its contents not being numbered.

One get into similar problems without `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{A}  A \end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{equation*} \label{B}  B \end{equation*}
 \end{subequations}
\begin{equation} \label{C}  C \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a workaround:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endsubequations}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}}{
  \ifnum\value{equation}=0\relax
    \addtocounter{parentequation}{-1}
  \fi
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
}{}{}
```

(edit: shorter patch and remembered the success/failure args)

Not sure if it covers everything. The idea is that if the `equation` counter is still zero at the end of the env, then besides resetting the `equation` value to what it was before `subequations` we also add `-1` to counter the `+1` that `subequations` added.

Note that the current solution gives duplicate destination warnings if combined with `hyperref`.

Comment: `\addtocounter{equation}{-1}` is not a good idea, with hyperref it will lead to duplicated destinations.

Comment: @Daleif: Where do I have to place the code you have suggested? Into the Subequations environment?@ Ulrike Fischer: So far there seems to exist no really robust solution?

Comment: @user288158 preamble

Comment: @UlrikeFischer better suggestion?

Comment: well depends what you want. In your example where nothing is numbered, the subequation looks quite pointless and probably counts are user error ...  For the showonlyrefs of mathtools, one probably would need a hook around the internal \refstepcounter, that would allow mathtools to replace that and perhaps add some manual target for hyperref.  The main problem is how mathtools then can detect that neither the env itself not the subequations have been referenced.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer exactly. If the OP hasn't registered an issue one it by tomorrow, I'll add one. Right, there is also the issue of the main eq number vs the subs. What to do if the main is referenced but not the subs...

Comment: It should be possible to reference to both the main-label (\label{eq:sub}) and sub-labels (e.g. \label{eq:1}), respectively (see my example above). But in case of \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}, a not referenced single equation or subequations placed earlyer in the document, must not increase the label-counter. This seems not to work?

Comment: @user288158 referencing `\eqref{eq:sub}` and not the sublabels make no sense as no equation number will ever be printed.

Comment: I think, I can live with the work around sugggested by Daleif - hopefully :-) .   Anyway, many thanks for your support!

Comment: So far the workaround suggested by Daleif works fine with respect to referencing. Equation labels are properly referenced. However, when non of the equations in a set of subequations is referenced, the text in the next line in the document is slightly indented. How can this be deleted? Thanks again in advance.